# Setting up two DIVs with lists inside an outer DIV

Tags: css

I am new to CSS and I would really like some help if possible.  What I need to do is something like below:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x                                   Line 1      Text 1 x
x                                   Line 2      Text 2 x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The area marked in x's is already defined as a DIV with name

```
<div id="hdr_sgn">
</div>
```

Inside that I need to create two DIV areas called hdr_msg4 and hdr_msg5. Inside each of these I need to create two lists without no list circles. Each list would have two rows and they need to be each 12px high. The two DIV areas need to be floating right and no spacing between them.

I am not sure how to set up the floating and things. Does anyone have any example they could show me?

Thanks for reading my post.

Comment: Do they have to be all these divs and lists, or are you just looking for a specific layout? Please describe your goal and your problem, and not just what you think should be the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
    <div id="hdr_sgn">
<div id="hdr_msg4">
    <ul>
        <li>Line 1</li>
        <li>Line 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="hdr_msg5">
    <ul>
        <li>Text 1</li>
        <li>Text 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="clr"></div>
```

CSS

```
    #hdr_sgn {
       width:100%;
       background-color:#eee;
    }
    #hdr_msg4, #hdr_msg5 {
       float:right;
    }
   #hdr_sgn ul {
      list-style:none;
    }
  .clr {
     clear:both;
    }
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EnJq8/

Comment: Thanks. What does the clr class do?

Comment: It clears any floats applied on elements before. Without this any preceding elements will also be floated right.

Answer (score 1):

Use the css attribute `float:right` for the floating divs (on both), `list-style-type:none` on the `<ul>` to remove the bullet points and `height:12px` for the height.

Are you okay with applying these? Or do you need a walk-through?

Comment: I will try. Do you think lists or a table would be best? I just have to be sure everything sits within the outer DIV and the maximum height is less than 25px.

Comment: Well you can manipulate both, but instinctively it looks more like a table problem than a list problem.

Answer (score 1):

That `line1` with `text1` next to it looks to me like a *definition list*. Check out the `dd` and `dt` tags to see how that works. I think that will make you achieve this layout easier.

Comment: Good tip... but somehow I have the feeling that OP will not enjoy dealing with different widths for different `dd` or `dt`.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a relation between hdr_msg4 and hdr_msg5 you should definitely use a regular table here! You propably heard that tables are bad practice for website layouts, but when you want to arrange a table, then use one!

Comment: I was thinking just two <ul> lists would be the most easy but yeah table might be a good way to go.

Comment: Not really any relation. Just two different areas (lists with two lines each).   hdr_msg5 needs to be right of hdr_msg4 and they both need to be pushed to the right hand side of the outer DIV